# Google maps only show provinces

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to only show the provinces of a country say Belgium?
I don't want roads, city names, bus stations, etc... Just the border of the country and it's provinces, like in this link http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Belgium_provinces_blank.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display country borders, US state borders, and city borders using Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397255/how-can-i-display-country-borders-us-state-borders-and-city-borders-using-goog)

Comment: Use the [Styled Map Wizard](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)