# displaying country borders only in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this jsfiddle :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/w6nxdoys/
```

I am using google map as a white empty map displaying only the markers 
what I need to do is display the countries borders with their labels 
I used a custom styled map like so :

```
  var styleArray =
                [

                    {
                        featureType: "all",
                        stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
                    },
                    {
                        featureType: "road",
                        stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
                    }

                ];


map.set('styles', styleArray);
```

How can i achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the borders, then use [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/) to apply to map, check that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727292/2683633)

Comment: is there any other way ??? if i want to use this method is there any javascript api ??? i did a some search and i could not find